# Bounding constants in terms of functions

Tags: logic

**Problem statement:**

Assume there are two constants $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$ and two functions $$f: A\times B \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \text{ and } g: A\times B \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$ non-negative, continuous, and bounded, $A$ and $B$ non-empty, such that $\forall b \in B, \exists a\in A$ with $\alpha \leq f(a,b)$ and $\forall a \in A, \exists b \in B$ with $\beta \leq g(a,b)$, then there exists a pair $(a,b) \in A \times B$ such that $$\alpha \leq f(a,b) \text{ and } \beta \leq g(a,b).$$

**My attempt:**

The statement seems like it should be trivial, but I find myself making what seems like a circular argument.

*Proof:*

Let $b\in B$, then by assumption there is an $a_b \in A$ such that $\alpha \leq f(a_b, b)$. Now, with $a_b$, there exists a $b_{a_b} \in B$ such that $\beta \leq g(a_b, b_{a_b})$. If $b=b_{a_b}$, then $g(a_b, b) = g(a_b, b_{a_b})$ and 
$$\alpha \leq f(a_b, b) \text{ and } \beta \leq g(a_b, b)$$
and so $(a_b, b)$ is a pair that satisfies the statement.

*Comment:*

My issue is, can I just write "if $b = b_{a_b}$"? Nothing prevents this from happening and since I just need existence this argument seems valid...

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are empty, then the preconditions hold vacuously but the consequence fails as there simply isn't *any* pair in $A\times B$.

Comment: For your comment, you can certainly say "if $b=b_{a_b}$ then" but you have to also handle the $b\neq b_{a_b}$ case, or you have to give an argument for what that case can't happen. You can't *just* say "if it is the case that..." because the obvious retort is then, "well, what if it isn't the case?"

Comment: Let $\alpha=\beta=1$ and $A=B=\{0,1\}$. Define $f(a,b)=a+b\pmod 2$ and $g(a,b)=1- f(a,b)\pmod 2$. $f$ and $g$ satisfy the preconditions ($f(a,1-a)=1$ and $g(a,a)=1$), but $f+g$ is the constantly $1$ function and thus less than $\alpha+\beta=2$. Perhaps you also have an unstated continuity assumption.

Comment: I modified the statement slightly, sorry for the unnecessary confusion.

Comment: Well, my counter-example was non-negative and bounded. So you will need to make use of the continuity assumption. The fact that your proof attempt would, if it worked, work just as well for non-continuous functions shows that something is missing/wrong and suggests a direction to look to find out what may need to be added.

Comment: I see what you mean... Thanks. I will have to think about it more.